# VirtualBox: USB device is busy with the previous request

Tags: windows, virtualbox, usb-flash-drive, arch-linux, windows-10

I want to use my pendrive on Arch Linux that is currently on VirtualBox. My host system is Windows 10.

I've already added a USB device filter, but Arch doesn't see any USB disk. When I try to connect with this pendrive other way: clicking on the USB cable icon on bottom-right corner and choosing my device, it says:

> USB device is busy with the previous request

I suppose that my pendrive is used by Windows and that's why it's "busy", but I have no idea how to make it available.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the **VirtualBox Guest Additions**, you may need to install [virtualbox-guest-utils](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=virtualbox-guest-utils) and your corresponding virtualbox-guest-modules (please check [this part](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Install_the_Guest_Additions) of the arch awesome wiki )

You have also to check whether your username is part of the group vboxusers.

Last thing, you may want to check if USB 2 (or 3) is being supported by your hypervisor otherwise you have to install an extension pack, please refer to [this part of the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#USB_subsystem_not_working)